# Fastest file reading in C++ with SSE instructions available

Tags: c++, optimization, file-io, sse

I have to read a 8k x 8k matrix from a file in fastest possible way. As of now I am using fstat and reading the entire file into memory and then operate on loaded data.

Is this the fastest possible way. I am working on x86 processor with SSE instructions available. Can i take their advantage for file reading?

Thanks

Comment: Do you store the matrix in binary or text format?

Answer (score 5):

SSE instructions won't speed up reading the file. That will be limited by your disk access.

Once you have the file in memory, then, if your compiler emits SSE instructions, the operations performed on the matrix will benefit.

Answer (score 1):

You could also look into using memory mapped files and transfer some of the buffering responsibility to the OS.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have all the data in memory before processing it, then the way you are already doing it looks like the best one.

SSE operations may help you in order to process the data, but they will not help you to load the data faster. Anyway, you may just give it a try an turn on the maximum optimization available in your compiler (for instance in GCC you could use -O3 and then specify one of the -msseX options). Of course, doing that would reduce the portability of your binary.